# Access Interval from Carbon Interval

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

```
CarbonInterval {#1680 ▼
  interval: + 00:07:36.0
  #tzName: null
  #localMonthsOverflow: null
  #localYearsOverflow: null
  #localStrictModeEnabled: null
  #localHumanDiffOptions: null
  #localToStringFormat: null
  #localSerializer: null
  #localMacros: null
  #localGenericMacros: null
  #localFormatFunction: null
  #localTranslator: null
  +"y": 0
  +"m": 0
  +"d": 0
  +"h": 0
  +"i": 0
  +"s": 456
  +"f": 0.0
  +"weekday": 0
  +"weekday_behavior": 0
  +"first_last_day_of": 0
  +"invert": 0
  +"days": false
  +"special_type": 0
  +"special_amount": 0
  +"have_weekday_relative": 0
  +"have_special_relative": 0
}
```

How can I access this `interval: + 00:07:36.0` value form this `CarbonPeriod` object.

Comment: Did you tried the obvious? $object->interval

Comment: How i can see here `interval` is public. So something like this

 `$a = new CarbonInterval();
$a->interval;` or `$a->getInterval()` or `$a->getDateInterval()`

Comment: Isn't this the value you set in the constructor e.g. years, months, days, hours, etc.?

Comment: the value i inserted is 456 seconds. I want this as hour:minutes:seconds

Answer (score 0):

`CarbonInterval` has a function called `cascade()` which will fill out the other fields accordingly.

Which will return `carbonInterval` object something like this.

```
 +"y": 0
 +"m": 0
 +"d": 0
 +"h": 0
 +"i": 7
 +"s": 36
 +"f": 0.0
```

Then we can access those properties or we can call `format('%H:%I:%s')` to get the desired value.

Example

```
$carbonInterval->cascade()->format('%H:%I:%s')
```